# java - Debezium cannot parse DDL (create proc) statements mysql connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have integrated the debezium connector in Kafka connect to stream my mysql db changes. For some procedures, it's unable to read the binlog files. Any suggestions or work-arounds? Stuck with this prob. Can I specify in mysql not to put ddl logs to binlog files?

```
2017-10-10 15:20:22,314 ERROR  MySQL|dbStreamer|binlog  Failed due to error: Error processing binlog event            [io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unexpected exception (One or more errors trying to parse statement at line 1, column 8) parsing at line 1, column 8
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:164)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:142)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:332)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:902)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:760)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:472)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$5.run(BinaryLogClient.java:657)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Unexpected exception (One or more errors trying to parse statement at line 1, column 8) parsing at line 1, column 8
at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parsingFailed(DdlParser.java:660)
at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parse(DdlParser.java:294)
at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parse(DdlParser.java:267)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:354)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleQueryEvent(BinlogReader.java:461)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:319)
... 5 more
Caused by: One or more errors trying to parse statement at line 1, column 8
io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Expecting VIEW at line 1, column 35 but found 'PROCEDURE': =`root`@`localhost`  ===>> PROCEDURE `azuga`.`c
io.debezium.text.ParsingException: No more content
```

Comment: It says **Expecting VIEW at line 1, column 35 but found 'PROCEDURE'**

Answer (score 0):

you need to raise an issue in the [issue tracker.](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DBZ) DDL parser is able to handle (skip) statements for creating procedures but is not perfect. If you could provide the code in question we can fi the parser.

Comment: Solved. Setting this property "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl" to true will ignore all the unparseable ddl statements.

Comment: This is more a hotfix then real solution. The problem is that if you in future meet other unparsable DDL that realtest not to a procedure but to tables you can and up in a situation when the schema will not conform to the data.

Comment: In Azure Mysql you will sometimes see DDL statements such as : "FLUSH FIREWALL_RULES" which are unparseable by Debezium. Adding this setting:
   "schema.history.internal.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true" (version >= 2.0.0) prevents from stopping the connector.